# Adventure game in QML only?

Tags: 2d, qml, game-engine, adventure

I would like to implement a simple 2D adventure game for desktop and android using QML(Qt Modeling Language).

The game will have different places, like e.g. kitchen and cellar. A place has typically a background image, and then some objects in that place. These might be some things you need to find and collect, or can also be simple sprites, like a bird flying through the room.

I have written a small first version with only one place, that works fine. Now I would like to extend the game.

I would like to implement the places isolated and separately, so I can easily switch between the places, e.g. you go from the kitchen to the cellar, and that places can easily be added.

I was looking for an appropriate way to do this in QML only, but it seems there is none.

Does anyone have a good idea, how to do this? Google hasn't helped me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda agree with Kakadu that this is not really a concrete question. I wanted to reply though, because your question sounds very similar to a small side project I'm working on, where I'm using a Flickable as the view onto the levels, and each level can be an Item, Image, etc. When the player gets to either edge of the level, the current level sets its opacity to 0 and sets its parent property to null. The new level then sets its parent to be the Flickable (view).

So, there are definitely ways to do this, and I'd recommend using Flickable with whatever type you'd like to use to represent your levels.

Comment: So you are basically recommending to use whatever container type is suits best (with a strong advise for `flickable`), und just switch visibility?

Comment: More or less, but I use opacity instead of visibility so that I can fade in/out between level changes. If you want some kind of scrollable view, then Flickable is a good choice.

Comment: Works. Thanks for the `flickable` hint.

Answer (score 1):

The first that comes to my mind is that:

- Root QML has number of QML items which represent zones (kitches, living rooms, etc.)
- Only one zone can be visible at every moment of time.
- Each zone has some areas where player can leave it.
- There is a global state which describes world. The state is available in all zones.
- When player does some actions zone can affect player. It can do it because player object can be accessible inside of the zone.
- When player leaves the zone it executes some code of Root item which switches zones. Root know about all zones, so it can get one by its id or some another unique description.

Anyway, I think that this question can have many answers. They will depend on how complex player object communicates with outer world of zones. I think that it will be a good idea to show some your code, maybe you have some brilliant ideas already.

I can't say that answers on this question will be always opinion-based and it is bad but this question seems to be not very concrete for SO, IMHO.

Comment: Do I get this right: use `item` for the place, and toggle visibility of the item when moving between places?

Comment: Not toggling only it. When you move from `house` to the `yard` you make `house` invisible and `yard` visible